# Standard Method of Simplifying Polynomial Formulas

Tags: performance, methods, polynomial-math

I am trying to reduce the time it takes for a (mostly) polynomial formula to complete, which is non-recursive. Does there exist a method in order to reduce the amount of processing required to complete a task?

For instance if I run the code:

```
if(distance > sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)) { doSomething(); }
```

this could be better implemented into:

```
if(distance*distance > dx*dx + dy*dy) { doSomething(); }
```

My question is, is there a standard way of knowing how simplify things like this, kind of like how if you have a formula, you follow PEMDAS to boiled down to a number. The equation I am trying to simplify is this:

```
offset = |distance*(xObj-xCamera)-base*(base-depth)-distance*base| / hypot(distance, base);
//variables are: distance, xObj, xCamera, base, depth;
```

I know a couple of ways to improve it, but more than anything I'd just like to know if I can solve this methodically vs intuition.

Comment: Possible, but more context is needed. Your offset formula is fair. But, if in a loop, what is invariant? If `distance` and `base` stay the same, you could replace the `hypot` call with `hyp` where this was done above the loop `hyp = hypot(distance,base)`. Also, `dbase = distance * base`. A good optimizer will probably see these invariants and generate the code as if you had hand coded these speedups. Also, you are using `base` and `distance` in two multiplies each. Rearrange this to reduce them to one each? Reorder subtract to eliminate abs?

Comment: Can you live with an analog/approximation of something? I assume `hypot(x,y)` is `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`, which is the most expensive [and the divide is slightly expensive]. So, could you live with an analog of offset that eliminates the `/ hypot(distance,base)`? Combining with your 1st example, how about a `hypot` that eliminates the `sqrt` [with a compensating adjustment in the offset formula]? The method: benchmark/measure each part and eliminate/adjust the most expensive first. (e.g.) Eliminating a sqrt is a bigger win than eliminating an add.